# Javascript/AJAX Only Works When Debugging

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently I'm trying to populate a site dynamically. When I step through the code, it works perfect. However, when I run it on page load as intended, it doesn't work. The relevant code is:

```
<body onload="populate_all(string)";>

function populate_all(string)
{
  var split = string.split(" ");
  for(i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
  {
    populate(split[i], 'main'); 
  }
} 

function populate(string, location)
{
  if (string.length==0)
  { 
   document.getElementById(location).innerHTML="";
   return;
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");

        divTag.className ="info";

        divTag.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        document.getElementById(location).appendChild(divTag);
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","populate.php?string="+string,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

I've read up on this issue enough to be pretty sure the php isn't the issue. Basically: I'm running a javascript function with AJAX several times in a loop and the code only works when I debug it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, "it doesn't work" isn't real clear. Instead of creating the divs I want, which is several divs with different information, it creates either only the last div or four instances of the last div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) `xmlhttp` locally.
2. Use a **different** variable name as `location`. [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) is a global variable, which holds properties and methods to manipulate the current location.

   ```
   function populate(string, s_location) {
       var xmlhttp;
   ```

Currently, you keep overwriting the `xmlhttp` variable in the `populate` method. As a result, the `xmlhttp` object points to the last request.

Comment: That did the trick! I love it when things are that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was this: [Use javascript variable outside success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691528/use-javascript-variable-outside-success-function/17691643#17691643)

When making calls to $.getJSON etc, with the debugger attached it fixes/alters the timing and scoping. I was updating a table cell value from an xhr response fired by timed background events, and I needed to be doing the cell updates in the nested success functions. With the debugger attached things magically worked.